# "command limit has been reached" svn commit error

Tags: svn

When i 'commit' my code, this error popped up

`"command limit has been reached"`

Hi has anybody encountered this kind of problem?

Tried looking all over the web or in here in SO, couldnt find clue how to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, there's a [network command limit](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-network-connection-limit.html) that may occur if you try to commit too many files simultaneously to a [remote repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.webdav.clients.html).

**References**

- [Common Issue: Permission problems when using remote content – ASP.NET Debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/08/15/common-issue-permission-problems-when-using-remote-content/)